# How to compose email in office 365 outlook using VBA?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web, outlook

I am able to compose email in **Desktop Microsoft outlook** using the below mentioned code. But this code is not working for **Microsoft office 365 web outlook**. Please provide me Code/Suggestion for composing mail in Microsoft office 365 web outlook.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 4"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I'm afraid you can't. Using VBA like yours requires desktop Outlook to be installed. There might be a way to send mails via PowerShell. Just like this as below:

```
$olFolderDrafts = 16
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$ns = $ol.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

# call the save method yo dave the email in the drafts folder
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$null = $Mail.Recipients.Add("XXX@YYY.ZZZ")  
$Mail.Subject = "PS1 Script TestMail"  
$Mail.Body = "  Test Mail  "
$Mail.save()
#get it back from drafts and update the body
$drafts = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderDrafts)
$draft = $drafts.Items | where {$_.subject -eq 'PS1 Script TestMail'}
$draft.body += "`n foo bar"
$draft.save()
```

Hope that give you new idea for this.

Thanks,

Simon